# Can't get acces to onedrive

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I'm newcomer in Azure development. So I've tried to create "walk through" app from microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/3-exercise-access-files-onedrive). When I trying to login to OneDriveClient by username and password I'm getting this error message : The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '. I couldn't found correct solution

Answer (score 2):

**WAY 1:**
If you have administrator to accept permissions to sign in, ask the administrator to grant permissions for the consent.
If this is not the scenario. Try next way

---

**WAY 2:**

1. Go to your sign in page .
2. Copy the url and paste it to notepad and see if there is `&prompt=consent.`

[image]
3. **Remove** prompt=consent , (if present)parameter from the
AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters from helper class.

Then try if sign-in is successful. If not let prompt=consent be **added** in helper class of application.
Also make sure you gave only required permissions in the settings .
Also refer : [configure-permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-permission-classifications?tabs=azure-portal), [manage-app-consent-policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-app-consent-policies)

---

**References:**

1. [fix-admin-consent-issues-aadsts65001](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-admin-consent-issues-aadsts65001/)
2. [manage-application-permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-application-permissions)
3. [v2-permissions-and-consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)
4. [configure-admin-consent-workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow)
5. [Manage user consent to apps in microsoft365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/user-consent?view=o365-worldwide)